How can I get the expected text size with an SVG Image used in an OpenLayers Icon?
The code below produces the following result for me:

I expected the text to be larger. The current size rendered is nearly unreadable.
Zooming in on the result and measuring the height,

I see that text is indeed only 8-9 pixels in height. When using Google Docs, for example, and using size 10 Roboto,

I measure a height of 12 pixels. If the text size was rendered like google docs, it would be readable.
I figure there is a scaling factor reducing the size of the text, but I am not sure where that scaling factor is coming from or how to get rid of it. It could be in either how I have specified by SVG or it could be coming from OpenLayers.
What do I need to change to get rid of this scaling factor and have the text rendered as expected?


const osm = new ol.source.OSM();

osm.setTileGridForProjection(
  "EPSG:4326",
  ol.tilegrid.createXYZ({ extent: [-180, -90, 180, 90] })
);

const tileLayer = new ol.layer.Tile({ source: osm });

const coordinate = [-97, 38];
const coordinate2 = [-97, 37];
const text = "99";
const padding = 4;
const rectSize = [20, 20];

const svg =
  '<?xml version="1.0"?>' +
  `<svg width="${rectSize[0]}" height="${rectSize[1]}" viewBox="0 0 ${rectSize[0]} ${rectSize[1]}" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">` +
  `<rect width="${rectSize[0]}" height="${rectSize[1]}" style="fill:black" />` +
  `<text x="50%" y="50%" font-family="Roboto" font-size="10" fill="white" dominant-baseline="central" text-anchor="middle">${text}</text>` +
  "</svg>";

const svgPoint = new ol.Feature({
  geometry: new ol.geom.Point(coordinate2),
  properties: {
    name: "svgPoint"
  }
});

const layer = new ol.layer.Vector({
  source: new ol.source.Vector({
    features: [svgPoint]
  }),

  style: (feature) => {
    const properties = feature.getProperties();
    let style;

    style = new ol.style.Style({
      image: new ol.style.Icon({
        opacity: 1,
        src: "data:image/svg+xml;base64," + btoa(svg)
      })
    });

    return style;
  }
});

const map = new ol.Map({
  target: "map",
  layers: [tileLayer, layer],
  view: new ol.View({
    projection: "EPSG:4326",
    center: coordinate,
    zoom: 5
  }),
  controls: ol.control.defaults.defaults({ attribution: false, zoom: false })
});

ol.proj.get("EPSG:4326").setExtent([-180, -85, 180, 85]);
#map {
  height: 256px;
  width: 256px;
}
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/openlayers/7.3.0/ol.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/openlayers/7.3.0/dist/ol.min.js"></script>

<div id="map"></div>




change the viewBox. I imagine what you really want is probably a fixed size viewBox.

What does the viewBox need to be changed to?

some values that make it display as you wish it to i.e. 4 numbers with the first two probably 0.

The viewBox already has four numbers with the first two set to 0 and the last two are the same as the width and height of the SVG.

They are fixed. They are fixed to be the same size of the SVG itself. I suppose I don't understand.

1 is a fixed number, so is 2, so is 3 etc. A variable is not a fixed constant value.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Not sure but part of the problem is you're not rendering in "Roboto" but in the browser defaults font (usually Times New Roman on macos, windows) which has more "tender" shapes. You can either switch to 'sans-serif' (will change across different browsers and OS) or you need to embed the font in the SVG marker to make it selfcontained. See codepen example. Quite likely you also need to tweak/increase the font-size (e.g rectsize*0.6).
